# how to import an exported function

Tags: javascript, blockchain, chai, sinon, supertest

I have a file name as "registerUser.js"

the data inside registerUser.js as follow

```
async function main(){
 //some code
}
module.exports=main
```

Now I am writing the testcases of registerUser.js, so how can I import "main" in my test file?

P.S.- while importing registerUser file it is giving me an error in restoring the function in testcase

Comment: Can u share how your are importing in test file

Comment: const register = require('../../../registerUser');

Comment: let mockObj = ""
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockObj = sandbox.stub(register, 'main');
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        mockObj.restore();
    });

This mockObj.restore() is giving me error

Answer (score 0):

In the file you want to export (*registerUser.js*):

```js
async function main(){
    //some code
}

module.exports = main
```

In the file you want to import (*test.spec.js*):

```js
let register = require('path/registerUser')
let resp = register();
```